# Inspecting and managing the Azure Service Bus dead letter queue

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm using an Azure Service Bus queue.

I need to implement a diagnostic web page to show the list of items in the 'dead letter queue' (DLQ), inspect it and when I decide, move a single DLQ message to the main queue for reprocessing.

I think I have to use the "Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" namespace, maybe the ManagementClient, but I'm not sure this is the right way to follow.

Does anyone have an example on how to do it?

I would like to implement something like the DLQ management of Service Bus Explorer that allows to submit a message again.

[image: Service Bus Explore Sample]

Comment: If you are considering an out of the box solution, you may look into Serverless360 to read your messages and diagnose it for further message processing.

Answer (score 0):

> I think I have to use the "Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" namespace,
>   maybe the ManagementClient, but I'm not sure this is the right way to
>   follow.

Since you're dealing with messages (i.e. data), you will need to use `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` namespace. Management namespace is for managing namespaces, queues, topics etc.

Please see this link for code samples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues.

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues#receive-messages-from-the-queue):

```
namespace CoreReceiverApp
{
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;

    class Program
    {
        // Connection String for the namespace can be obtained from the Azure portal under the 
        // 'Shared Access policies' section.
        const string ServiceBusConnectionString = "<your_connection_string>";
        const string QueueName = "<your_queue_name>";
        static IQueueClient queueClient;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            queueClient = new QueueClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, QueueName);

            Console.WriteLine("======================================================");
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER key to exit after receiving all the messages.");
            Console.WriteLine("======================================================");

            // Register QueueClient's MessageHandler and receive messages in a loop
            RegisterOnMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages();

            Console.ReadKey();

            await queueClient.CloseAsync();
        }

        static void RegisterOnMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages()
        {
            // Configure the MessageHandler Options in terms of exception handling, number of concurrent messages to deliver etc.
            var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
            {
                // Maximum number of Concurrent calls to the callback `ProcessMessagesAsync`, set to 1 for simplicity.
                // Set it according to how many messages the application wants to process in parallel.
                MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,

                // Indicates whether MessagePump should automatically complete the messages after returning from User Callback.
                // False below indicates the Complete will be handled by the User Callback as in `ProcessMessagesAsync` below.
                AutoComplete = false
            };

            // Register the function that will process messages
            queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessagesAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
        }

        static async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
        {
            // Process the message
            Console.WriteLine($"Received message: SequenceNumber:{message.SystemProperties.SequenceNumber} Body:{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");

            // Complete the message so that it is not received again.
            // This can be done only if the queueClient is created in ReceiveMode.PeekLock mode (which is default).
            await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);

            // Note: Use the cancellationToken passed as necessary to determine if the queueClient has already been closed.
            // If queueClient has already been Closed, you may chose to not call CompleteAsync() or AbandonAsync() etc. calls 
            // to avoid unnecessary exceptions.
        }

        static Task ExceptionReceivedHandler(ExceptionReceivedEventArgs exceptionReceivedEventArgs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Message handler encountered an exception {exceptionReceivedEventArgs.Exception}.");
            var context = exceptionReceivedEventArgs.ExceptionReceivedContext;
            Console.WriteLine("Exception context for troubleshooting:");
            Console.WriteLine($"- Endpoint: {context.Endpoint}");
            Console.WriteLine($"- Entity Path: {context.EntityPath}");
            Console.WriteLine($"- Executing Action: {context.Action}");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

It's a console app that receives messages from a queue. In order to receive messages from DLQ, you simply need to change the name of the queue to `<your-queue-name>/$deadletterqueue`.

Again this code creates a receiver that constantly receives the messages from a queue and since you are building a webpage, you will need to receive messages on demand or implement some kind of websocket kind of functionality so that server can push the changes to the client.

Comment: So, probably I can "receive" the DLQ messages and store them in my database calling for example a webapi of my web app. This could be a solution. In this while I found the "Service Bus Explorer" (image in the edit I did) that does what I'm looking for.
I'll try to understand if it receives all the messages from the DLQ (not removing from the queue) or if it is able to iterate between the messages and manage the single item. What do you think it does?

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus is now deprecated, MSFT encourages using their new package: [Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus_7.7.0/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/README.md);
classes: ServiceBusProcessor or ServiceBusReceiver